# SOAP Web Services develoment support

Tags: web-services, soap, programming-languages

I am developing an appplication that consume data from WCF Web Service, but the data need to be retrieve from differents servers applications provided by different suppliers.

The question is what programming language support the develop of a Web Services from a WSDL that already exist?

For example in .NET you could use "wsdl.exe /serverInterface" to generate a server interface. See [Implementing Service Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649878.aspx)

In Java see: [Top Down Java Bean Web Service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M3/tutorials/TopDownWebService.html)

But I don't want the suppliers to be attached to an explicit tecnology.

Comment: Actually, wsdl.exe is legacy technology. You should use svcutil.exe, or "Add Service Reference".

Answer (score 1):

> ... I don't want the suppliers to be attached to an explicit tecnology.

You are taking about web services. The idea with web services is that it allows interactions between heterogeneous machines (and technologies).

For the interaction to happen, there is no need for the machine to use the same programming language or technology. What's important is the protocol used. In your case SOAP.

The protocol defines the communication interface or **contract**. For web services, the interface is described by the Web Services Description Language (your WSDL).

WSDL is in a (more or less) human readable format, but more importantly in a machine-processable format. The idea is that you use the WSDL to generate the code/classes that respect the contract; at the server side they are called Skeletons, and at the client side, Stubs.

A lot of programming languages have means or tools to generate stubs/skeletons from WSDL but again, that's not the important part. **The important part is respecting the contract**.

The WSDL just allows you to automate the creation of some boilerplate code. It's not mandatory to use the WSDL to create the server/client so any technology can be used (with or without the WSDL).

As long as you do that, you do not attach yourself to an explicit technology. So in the "WCF Web Service" you mention, you can drop the "WCF" word.

The only **care you must take is with the interface between the systems**. You must ensure the [Web Services Interoperability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Interoperability) as we don't live in an ideal world and some specifics from the technology stack "could leak" in the contract if you are not careful.